# Invalid Column Name: "value" - Error Even though it works in another form.

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am stuck at one problem and I just can't solve this.
I get this Error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWGPa.jpg)

[That's the relevant table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HmfW.jpg)

The Code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        string query = "UPDATE CAC SET nextMaintainance = @nextMaintainance WHERE department = " + @departmentCB.Text;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nextMaintainance", nextMaintainanceDT.Value);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The weird thing I don't understand is that a similar code works just fine without any error in my project:

```
query = "UPDATE LDV SET received = @received, department = @department WHERE Id =" + @idTxt.Text;
            command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@received", inDT.Value);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", departmentCb.Text);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Lungenautomat wurde aktualisiert");
```

If relevant, my connection string:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCBA_Manager_0._1.Properties.Settings.SCBAmanagerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

I really hope you can help me :( 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `department` column is a text column, so comparing it to a value means the value should be wrapped in quotes.

```
// This fix is not the recommended approach, see the explanation after this code block  
string query = "UPDATE CAC SET nextMaintainance = @nextMaintainance WHERE department = '" + departmentCB.Text + "'";
                                                                                   //  ^--------------------------^------ single quote added to wrap the value returned by departmentCB.Text
```

On the other hand, this error does not occur in your second example, because there you're correctly using the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method to add the value for the `@department` parameter, and because `id` is a numeric column, so it doesn't require the value wrapped in quotes.

However, while the code shown above does the job, it is not the right way of doing the job. The correct way is to used parameters for all values to be injected into a query. The queries you've shown above are already correctly using parameters for some values (e.g. `nextMaintenance` in the first query, `received` and `department` in the second), but are incorrectly doing string concatenation for other values (e.g. `department` in the first query, `id` in the second).

**Usage of Parameterized SQL**

The benefit of using parameterized SQL is that it automatically takes care of adding quotes, prevents SQL injection, etc.

Therefore, its best to change your first code block to:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
string query = "UPDATE CAC SET nextMaintainance = @nextMaintainance WHERE department = @department";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", departmentCb.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nextMaintainance", nextMaintainanceDT.Value);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice how the string `query` is a single string without any messy concatenation, and that it contains two parameters `@nextMaintenance` and `@department`? And how the values for those parameters are correctly injected using `Parameters.AddWithValue()` in the following lines?

Your second code block can be similarly improved by using a parameter for the `Id` column.

```
query = "UPDATE LDV SET received = @received, department = @department WHERE Id = @Id ";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", idTxt.Text);
```

---

**Further Information**

Do read up about SQL injection ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx ) to see how using string concatenation like your original code can lead to various security issues, and why parameterized queries are the preferred way of injecting dynamic values into SQL queries.

You can read up more about parameterized queries here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: God damn it, I tried this already, but it didn't work. Now I tried it again and it did work. Strange, but thank you a lot!!!
But maybe to avoid further errors like this, I will try parameterized SQL Thank you for your tip!

Comment: You're welcome, @USAfirefighter. If this answer helped you solve your issue, please do mark it as _Answered_

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, the WHERE clause evaluates to

```
WHERE department = Kasseedorf
```

wheras it should be

```
WHERE department = 'Kasseedorf'
```

So the line should be

```
string query = "UPDATE CAC SET nextMaintainance = @nextMaintainance WHERE department = '" + @departmentCB.Text +"'";
```

It works in the second example, because id is an integer and doesn't neet quotes.

Comment: God damn it, I tried this already, but it didn't work. Now I tried it again and it did work. Strange, but thank you a lot!!!